# Understanding Outlets in Interface Builder

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, cocoa-touch, interface-builder

I'm doing an exercise to try to truly understand Interface Builder and Outlets.

Using Xcode 4.0 I've chosen the template for Window Based Application. I then:

1. Go into Interface Builder and add a UINavigation Controller.
2. Set the Window Outlet RootView Controller to the Navigation Controller.
3. Go to AppDelegate.h to create a UINavigation Controller called
   navController and give it an IBOutlet.
4. Go to AppDelegate.m in the didFinishLaunchingWithOptions to set
   self.window.rootViewController to self.navController.
5. Create a new UIViewController called FirstViewController complete
   with .xib file.

My question is, how do I set the root view controller in the mainWindow.xib outlet as the FirstViewController? But more importantly could someone explain to me the reasoning behind how you do this?

In other words, I would like FirstViewController to be the first view controller the user sees in my app. And I would like to understand exactly the mechanics behind making this happen.

Thanks for all the help!

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

interface bilder's outlets is just a links between graphical part of your program, and your code. In other words, they explane what code controlls this graphical object. You see, objective-c is very MVC-oriented. .xib file is V(view), outlet and your code, that linked with .xib by this outlet - is C(controller). M(model) should be somewhere alse in your code.

Now, about root view controller. I prefer implement it like below:
import your firstViewController to AppDeledate.h and implement navigationController:

```
#import "firstViewController .h"
@class firstViewController
...
UINavigationController *navigationController;
...
@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UINavigationController *navigationController;
```

now, in interfacebuilder (mainWindow.xib), add navigationController object and link it with implemented property. Then, add a ViewController object in that navigationController, select this ViewController Object and set in inspectors it's class to `firstViewController` and xib file to `firstViewController`. Finaly, in  AppDelegate.m in the `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions` to set `self.window.rootViewController` to `self.navigationController`. That's it.